# How to restrict every user roles in JSP/Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to provide many users in my JPS web application. I dont want to have many pages to be redirected for every user. I only want one page for all the user. For example, I have one page that contains add, edit and delete button which is the primary or only role of the admin users. If the login user is not admin I dont want any user to have access for add, edit and delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible even if you are using same JSP page for different role. JSP compiled in server and transformed into raw HTML & js before sending it to client.

So in JSP page you can put condition basis of user role. like -

LoginServlet -

```
public class LonginServelt extends HttpServlet{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        User user = userService.checkUserCredential(username,password);
        Session session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("user",user);
    }
}

<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${isAdmin}">
    You got Gold 
  </c:when>

  <c:when test="${isCustomer}">
    You got Silver 
  </c:when>

  <c:when test="${isProducer}">
    You got Bronze 
  </c:when>

  <c:otherwise>
    Better luck next time 
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

So when user hit this page with different role in server itself it will populate role depended html.

> Note : you can even use scriplet to put condition which is treated as
>   old technology.

Comment: But how can I set the user role upon login and calling the value in my jsp page?

Comment: you must validate the user credential in login and that user dto or model you should save into server-session(request.getSession(false)). and you will get the user role in jsp page from the session.

Comment: sorry but Im finding myself more difficult to understand this part because im really new with this one...Can you provide me a sample solution for this one?thanks :)

Comment: check [Example](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html)

Comment: I tried to use your example above...Im added to jstl jar file to my build path but Still I have this error
rg.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp (line: 1, column: 1) The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: Thanks it worked!
But How can I correclty compare my session variable?I have this code
'<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value='<%=session.getAttribute("theName" ) %>' />
<c:if test="${salary == 121}">
    <a href="create-news-item">Create News Item</a>
</c:if>'
When I tried to chage the value of salary to 121 the create link shows. But when I direclty call the session the create link doesnt show...

Comment: `<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value='<%= session.getAttribute( "theName" ) %>' />
     <c:if test="${salary == 121}">
      <a href="create-news-item">Create News Item</a>
      <br />
     </c:if>`

Comment: Strange login example. If session hasn't been created yet, you're not logging in? Just use `getSession()` without the boolean argument. It'll autocreate the session when not created yet.

Comment: @BalusC exactly what getSession(true) does. Thanks for your comment quite worthwhile. :)

Answer (score 1):

what you want is a filter a sessionfilter to be precise, you can try these:

i assume you have a user class if not:

User.java

```
public class User implements Serializable {
  private int accountId;
  private String loginId;
  private Role type;

  public User(int accountId, String loginId, Role type) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
    this.loginId = loginId;
    this.type = type;
  }

  public User() {
    this.accountId = -1;
    this.loginId = null;
    this.type = null;
  }

  public void setRole(Role type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public Role getRole() {
    return this.type;
  }

  public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
  }

  public int getAccountId() {
    return this.accountId;
  }

  public void setLoginId(String loginId) {
    this.loginId = loginId;
  }

  public String getLoginId() {
    return this.loginId;
  }
}
```

you can also create an enum for your role types:

Role.java

```
public enum Role {

  ADMINISTRATOR, STAFF;
}
```

in your login.jsp, this is just an example to give you an idea:

```
<%
  //put your login query stuff here
  User user = new User();
  user.setAccountId(1);
  user.setLoginId("adminaccount01);
  user.setRole(Role.ADMINISTRATOR);
  session.setAttribute("LOGIN_USER", user);
%>
```

here is the filter: **SessionCheckFilter.java**

```
public class SessionCheckFilter implements Filter {

    private String contextPath;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
        contextPath = fc.getServletContext().getContextPath();
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;                        

        User user = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("LOGIN_USER");
        if (user == null) {                
                //put your redirect stuff here
                res.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/to_your_login.jsp");                
        } else {
            switch (user.getRole()) {
                case ADMINISTRATOR:
                        //put your redirect stuff here
                        res.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/redirect_to_your_admin_path/admin_page.jsp");
                    break;
                case STAFF:
                        //put your redirect stuff here
                        res.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/redirect_to_staff_path/staff_page.jsp");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            fc.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

and add don't forget to add these to **web.xml**

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>SessionCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>package_name_if_there_is_any.SessionCheckFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/your_path/*</url-pattern> 
  </filter-mapping>
```